# Can "typedef typename" be replaced by "using" keyword in C++ 11

Tags: c++11, typedef, using, typename

I know that the "using" keyword could be used as template alias and type alias, but I didn't see anyone has mentioned that "typedef typename" could be replaced by "using". So could it?

Answer (score 7):

A declaration of the following form

```
typedef typename something<T>::type alias;
```

can be replaced by

```
using alias = typename something<T>::type;
```

The `typename` is still necessary, but it does look neater, and having that `=` in the middle of the line is aesthetically pleasing since we are defining an alias. The main selling point of using is that it can be templated.

```
template <typename T>
using alias = typename something<T>::type;
```

You can't do that with `typedef` alone. The C++98 equivalent would be this slightly monstrous syntax.

```
template <typename T>
struct Alias {
  typedef typename something<T>::type type;
};

// Then refer to it using typename Alias<T>::type.
// Compare to the C++11 alias<T>, which is much simpler.
```

The other major selling point of `using` over `typedef` is that it looks much cleaner when defining function aliases. Compare

```
// C++98 syntax
typedef int(*alias_name)(int, int);
// C++11 syntax
using alias_name = int(*)(int, int);
```

Comment: "using alias = typename something<T>::type;" would you please explain why "typename" on the right side of "=" is still needed?

Comment: @PeterHan `typename` never was necessary, unless code would be ambigous, the only other use is that it may replace `class` in templates

Answer (score 1):

`using` can replace type declaration in case if you use it as alias of another type or if you can declare this type. Syntax is:

> **using** identifier attr(optional) = type-id ;   (1)
>
> **template** < template-parameter-list > **using** identifier attr(*optional*) = type-id ; (2)

*type-id*   -   abstract declarator or any other valid type-id (which may introduce a new type, as noted in type-id). **The type-id cannot directly or indirectly refer** to identifier.

So, this cannot be replaced by  single `using`, you need two:

```
typedef struct MyS 
{
   MyS *p;
} MyStruct, *PMyStruct;
```